# CURAND failure 105 and Python

Tags: cntk

I am getting this problem each time I try to use a learner with gaussian_noise_injection_std_dev>0.
According to an answer provided to issue #444 on the GitHub site, the solution is to do initialization on CPU, but I can't find this option in the Python APIs.

CURAND failure 105: (see curand.h & look for curandStatus or CURAND_STATUS_xxx) ; GPU=0 ; hostname=ROSIE ; expr=curandGenerateNormal(((curandGenerator_t*) s_curandGenerator)[0], reinterpret_cast(Data()), GetNumElements(), (float) mean, (float) sigma)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "", line 5, in 
trainer.train_minibatch(data) # update model with it
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\cntk\trainer.py", line 120, in train_minibatch
arguments, device)
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 2022, in train_minibatch_overload_for_minibatchdata
return _cntk_py.Trainer_train_minibatch_overload_for_minibatchdata(self, args)
RuntimeError: CURAND failure 105: (see curand.h & look for curandStatus or CURAND_STATUS_xxx) ; GPU=0 ; hostname=ROSIE ; expr=curandGenerateNormal(((curandGenerator_t) s_curandGenerator)[0], reinterpret_cast(Data()), GetNumElements(), (float) mean, (float) sigma)
[CALL STACK]

> Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::CudaTimer:: Stop
>   - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::GPUMatrix:: SetGaussianRandomValue
>   - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::Matrix:: SetGaussianRandomValue
>   - CNTK::Internal:: ZeroesWithDynamicAxesLike
>   - CNTK::Internal:: ZeroesWithDynamicAxesLike
>   - CNTK:: SGDLearner
>   - CNTK::TrainingParameterSchedule:: Serialize
>   - CNTK::Trainer:: TotalNumberOfSamplesSeen
>   - CNTK::Trainer:: TrainMinibatch
>   - CNTK::Trainer:: TrainMinibatch
>   - PyInit__cntk_py
>   - PyInit__cntk_py
>   - PyCFunction_Call
>   - PyEval_GetFuncDesc
>   - PyEval_EvalFrameEx
>   - PyEval_EvalFrameEx
>   I have GTX 970, 4GB, running beta 12 on Win10.

Regards,
Slawek

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this is now in master. CNTK 2.0rc2 will work correctly.